# How Google Chrome Installer works from Internet Explorer without being downloaded first?

Tags: c#, browser, installation, add-in

If you click on the [Download Chrome button](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/features.html?utm_source=bing&utm_medium=sem&utm_campaign=1001342%7CChromeWin10%7CUS%7Cen%7CHybrid%7CText%7CBKWS~Exact&brand=CHBF&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1001342%20%7C%20Chrome%20Win10%20%7C%20US%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20Hybrid%20%7C%20Text%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20Exact&utm_term=download%20chrome&utm_content=Download%20-%20Exact&dclid=CJD_sNq7hNYCFW-1swodQSYBqw) in (ONLY seems to work in Internet Explorer) a browser, the installation starts right away and download files itself. I would like to know what technology is behind this? Is it the Omaha installer thing?

In this case, instead of popping the bar (Do you want to Run or Save...) at the bottom, IE displays a rather customized EULA pop up with the "Accept" button. I would love to know how that is achieved.

What I want to do is just to place my own Windows App installer/*.EXE in an intranet site so that any users can just click and have the program started without needing to know how to download first and look for the file to install. As far as security is concern, it's Intranet, so I'm not worried about security.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to hit f12 and figure it out?

Comment: Yea, but too complex to figure out. There's a possibility of OneClick, but I need to be sure because I am not familiar with OneClick. Since OneClick and Omaha are being mentioned on google search for something that could be close to this, I just need a clearer direction. I'm not going to read something that has nothing to do with what I need to achieve.